# How to count primary key of one table in another table?

Tags: mysql

How to count primary key of one table which is used in another table in 5 to 6 column?

If `table1` has primary key `srno` which is used in `table2` in column `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`.

I want to count how many times `srno=1,2,3,4`... etc used in `table2`.

Does anyone know how to do that???

Comment: What do you mean by "table" here? Is this an SQL question?

Comment: Your question is entirely based on SQL, so please provide the database you are using (mysql or ...). Also should it be a count for all records in table 1 or only for a specific index?

Comment: yes, its SQL question.

Comment: suppose i have two table, Table1 and Table2.
In Table1 i have 4 record t1,t2,t3,t4
then i want to count how many times t1 used in Table2 and so on..

Comment: Please add an example of what your expected result should look like. Do you need one row for each record from table1, or are you asking for a specific primary key?

Comment: i am asking for specific primary key. like how many times 1 or 2 or 3 etc usd inn Table2?

Comment: could you please give your db structure,Or create a fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: bt the problem is primary key of Table1 is used in multiple columns of Table2

Comment: customer(srno,code,hname,state,city PRIMARY KEY (`srno`)) this is Table1
weekly(w_id,wk,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10) This is Table2
srno of customer used in weekly in column d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10 so i want to count how many times 1st record of customer used in whole weekly table. anyone know solution??

Comment: Please add an example of expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return the number of times each value used in columns d1, d2, d3 and d4 in table2 (**Updated**):

```
SELECT table1.srno, SUM(cnt) FROM
  table1,
  (SELECT d1 AS srno, COUNT(d1) AS cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY d1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d2 AS srno, COUNT(d2) AS cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY d2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d3 AS srno, COUNT(d3) AS cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY d3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d4 AS srno, COUNT(d4) AS cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY d4) AS cnt_tbl
WHERE table1.srno = cnt_tbl.srno
GROUP BY table1.srno
```

Try fiddle [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23cad/3/0)

If you're counting only one specific primary key (e.g. 1), then try

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE d1 = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE d2 = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE d3 = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE d4 = 1) AS cnt_tbl
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0074e/7/0).

Or a more elegant solution without UNION:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM
  (SELECT ((d1=1) + (d2=1) + (d3=1) + (d4=1)) AS cnt 
   FROM table2 
   WHERE d1 = 1 OR d2= 1 OR d3 = 1 OR d4 = 1) AS cnt_tbl
```

([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0074e/5/0))

Comment: I think you need `UNION ALL` otherwise duplicates will be suppressed.

Comment: srno of table1 used in multiple columns. above code is for specific record, bt records can b multiple.

Comment: Ok, and the first query listed doesn't answer your question either? Or is the problem that you need to join the result with table1?

Comment: Ok, I updated the first query, does it help now?

Comment: Please, just add a sample output. I don't get what you mean by 1st record of customer. Is the 1st record some special record?

Comment: You've got me completely lost. For the last time, without example of *expected output* for *sample input data* I cannot do more for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(PK_COL1_NAME_IN_TABLE2) FROM TABLE2
```

See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).